# Stored time as number. Problem with formatting - 00 as seconds

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, format

Time is stored as a number in my database - NUMBER(6)

When it comes to past-midnight time, it is stored like this `1800`. So basically `00:18:00`

I'm using `lpad` to have it in 6 characters `lpad(TIME,6,0)` and it gives me `001800`.

However, when I want to cast it into timestamp `TO_TIMESTAMP(lpad(TIME,6,0), 'HH24MISS')` it gives me the only first day of the month.

`2019-07-01`

When time is `000713(00:07:13)`, it is converted without problems

`2019-07-01 00:07:13`

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: You want `TO_CHAR()`, not `TO_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: Its giving me `ORA-01481: invalid number format model`. `TO_CHAR(lpad(TIME,6,0), 'HH24MISS')`

Comment: @timetravelprimer I can not understand your Problem => *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6fde670338a7abd73cd02a4694872d64)*

Comment: I agree with @hotfix - after messing with this a bit more I don't see why you're having a problem. `TO_TIMESTAMP(LPAD(1800,6,0), 'HH24:MI:SS')` produces `01-JUL-19 12.18.00.000000000 AM` just as I'd expect. `TO_TIMESTAMP(LPAD(713,6,0), 'HH24MISS')` produces `01-JUL-19 12.07.13.000000000 AM`, again precisely what I'd expect. ???

Comment: select to_char(to_timestamp('001800','HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),'HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from dual; try this one

Comment: @MansiRaval why so complicated?  `select to_char('001800','00G00G00','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '' :''') from dual;`